# How to create a Multi purpose Logic app in Azure which serves all email activity?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, etl, azure-logic-apps

I am writing a ETL script in Python Azure function where I want to send emails about the job status and process trackability to different owners. I am trying to create a logic app which is more dynamic and serves multipurpose requirements as mentioned below:

| Situation | Subject | Email_to | Body | Attachment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| When Python code throws error | Code Error | abc@outlook.com, def@outlook.com | Error code Info | No |
| When code ran successfully | Etl Success | ghy@outlook.com, def@outlook.com | Etl process successful | No |
| When we write qc_file.csv to blob storage | QC Sheet | uwj@outlook.com, jsh@outlook.com | please find the Qc_Sheet | qc_file.csv |

I think I need to create the logic app with switch case since I am very new to logic app, I am confused to do so.

Comment: This isn’t an issue. Have a go first and then let us know if you still need help. Just start …!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your requirement, you can create 2 logic apps. One to achieve first 2 situations and the other logic app for the last situation.

**Logic App 1:**

In order to achieve the error situation, you can use run after for mail step. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

Below are the settings in my run after.

[image]

Code view of Logic App1

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "HttpTrigger1": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "name": ""
                    },
                    "function": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/fa75518485/functions/HttpTrigger1"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Function"
            },
            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Body": "<p>Error code Info</p>",
                        "Importance": "Normal",
                        "Subject": "Code Error",
                        "To": "abc@outlook.com; def@outlook.com"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "HttpTrigger1": [
                        "FAILED"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Send_an_email_(V2)_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Body": "<p>Etl process successful</p>",
                        "Importance": "Normal",
                        "Subject": "Etl Success",
                        "To": "ghy@outlook.com; def@outlook.com"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "HttpTrigger1": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Logic App 2:**

As soon as the file gets uploaded to storage account, the mail will get triggered. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

Code view of Logic App2

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Get_blob_content_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(triggerBody()?['Path']))}/content",
                    "queries": {
                        "inferContentType": true
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Send_an_email_(V2)_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Attachments": [
                            {
                                "ContentBytes": "@{base64(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'))}",
                                "Name": "@triggerBody()?['Name']"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Body": "<p>please find the Qc_Sheet</p>",
                        "Importance": "Normal",
                        "Subject": "QC Sheet",
                        "To": "uwj@outlook.com; jsh@outlook.com"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_blob_content_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_blob_is_added_or_modified_(properties_only)_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/triggers/batch/onupdatedfile",
                    "queries": {
                        "checkBothCreatedAndModifiedDateTime": false,
                        "folderId": "JTJmbXljb250YWluZXI="
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmbXljb250YWluZXI=": "/mycontainer"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/azureblob"
                },
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```